# iOS Obj-C - How to create NSDictionary from object containing NSArray, but only use specific fields?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, nsdictionary

I want to create JSON containing a few objects including an NSArray of custom objects (one of which is also an NSArray). For the objects in the NSArray, I only want to save specific fields (some of which are basic C/C++ types - ie. int, bool, etc.).

At the moment I'm using NSKeyedArchiver with the NSArray objects conforming to the NSCoding protocol, where I can save the specific fields (converting the POD's to NSObject's) in the encodeWithCoder method.

An example of the JSON I want to create is as follows (comments show data type in object):

```
{
    "title:"My Title", // NSString
    "revision":1, // int
    "tasks": [    // NSArray
                  { // Is this necessary ?
                    "task": { // task object
                        "name": "Task 1", // NSString
                        "repeat": 1, // int
                        "sub_tasks": [ // NSArray
                            { // Is this necessary ?
                                "sub_task": { // sub task object
                                    "name":"Do This", // NSString
                                    "repeat":2 // int
                                },
                                "sub_task": {
                                    "name":"Do That",
                                    "repeat":2
                                }
                            } // Is this necessary ?
                        ]
                    },
                    "task": { // task object
                        "name": "Task 2", // NSString
                        "repeat": 1, // int
                        "sub_tasks": [ // NSArray
                            { // Is this necessary ?
                                "sub_task": { // sub task object
                                    "name":"Do This", // NSString
                                    "repeat":2 // int
                                },
                                "sub_task": {
                                    "name":"Do That",
                                    "repeat":2
                                }
                            } // Is this necessary ?
                        ]
                    }
                  } // Is this necessary ?
             ], // tasks NSArray
    "another_string":"some text" // NSString
}
```

Quick JSON question - Not sure the structure of the arrays is correct (specifically the opening "{" just after the start of the array "["). Is it needed ?

My first attempt to create JSON is to use `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:...]` to build up dictionary, and then use `[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:]` with dictionary as parameter to create JSON. However, I'm stuck on the dictionary creation part. I've started with the following:

```
NSDictionary* info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"The Title", @"title",
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:revision], @"revision",
                          // How to create the tasks array ???
```

but am not sure how to add the NSArray and sub-NSArray, **while only adding specific members of the array objects (ie. I don't want all the member fields - eg. For the task object, I want name, repeat and sub-tasks array, but not the date field, and I need to convert repeat field to NSNumber object)**.

How can I do this in Objective-C ?

Comment: in order to make sure your JSON is formatted correctly, you can use a JSON Linter. There is an online version here: https://jsonlint.com

Comment: Also to learn how to create NSDictionary in code, check out http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/nsdictionary-literals-in-objective-c.html

Answer (score 0):

By using object literals, you can create a JSON object dictionary like this:

```
NSDictionary *jsonObject = @{
 @"title": @"My Title",
 @"revision": @(1),
 @"tasks": @[
             @{
                 @"task": @{
                         @"name": @"Task 2",
                         @"repeat": @(1),
                         @"sub_tasks": @[
                                 @{
                                     @"sub_task": {
                                         @"name": @"Do That",
                                         @"repeat": @(2)
                                     }
                                 }
                             ]
                     }
                 }
             ],
 @"another_string": @"some text"
 };
```

By adding the `@` in front of numbers, brackets, and braces, it will create NSNumber, NSDictionary, and NSArray objects.

Answer (score 0):

What you've shared is invalid JSON because it contains duplicate keys within the same object, contains comments, and there's invalid syntax at `"title:"` where the colon is inside the key.

Here is the correct JSON for what you're trying to represent:

```json
{
  "title": "My Title",
  "revision": 1,
  "tasks": [
    {
      "name": "Task 1",
      "repeat": 1,
      "sub_tasks": [
        {
          "name": "Do This",
          "repeat": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "Do That",
          "repeat": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Task 2",
      "repeat": 1,
      "sub_tasks": [
        {
          "name": "Do This",
          "repeat": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "Do That",
          "repeat": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "another_string": "some text"
}
```

I used [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io#l=objc) to generate the following interface and implementation code. Here's `DMTasks.h`:

```objective-c
// To parse this JSON:
//
//   NSError *error;
//   DMTasks *tasks = [DMTasks fromJSON:json encoding:NSUTF8Encoding error:&error]

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class DMTasks;
@class DMTask;
@class DMSubTask;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

#pragma mark - Object interfaces

@interface DMTasks : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger revision;
@property (nonatomic, copy)   NSArray<DMTask *> *tasks;
@property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *anotherString;

+ (_Nullable instancetype)fromJSON:(NSString *)json encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding error:(NSError *_Nullable *)error;
+ (_Nullable instancetype)fromData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *_Nullable *)error;
- (NSString *_Nullable)toJSON:(NSStringEncoding)encoding error:(NSError *_Nullable *)error;
- (NSData *_Nullable)toData:(NSError *_Nullable *)error;
@end

@interface DMTask : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger repeat;
@property (nonatomic, copy)   NSArray<DMSubTask *> *subTasks;
@end

@interface DMSubTask : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger repeat;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

And the implementation `DMTasks.m`:

```
#import "DMTasks.h"

#define λ(decl, expr) (^(decl) { return (expr); })

static id NSNullify(id _Nullable x) {
    return (x == nil || x == NSNull.null) ? NSNull.null : x;
}

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface DMTasks (JSONConversion)
+ (instancetype)fromJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
- (NSDictionary *)JSONDictionary;
@end

@interface DMTask (JSONConversion)
+ (instancetype)fromJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
- (NSDictionary *)JSONDictionary;
@end

@interface DMSubTask (JSONConversion)
+ (instancetype)fromJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
- (NSDictionary *)JSONDictionary;
@end

static id map(id collection, id (^f)(id value)) {
    id result = nil;
    if ([collection isKindOfClass:NSArray.class]) {
        result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[collection count]];
        for (id x in collection) [result addObject:f(x)];
    } else if ([collection isKindOfClass:NSDictionary.class]) {
        result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[collection count]];
        for (id key in collection) [result setObject:f([collection objectForKey:key]) forKey:key];
    }
    return result;
}

#pragma mark - JSON serialization

DMTasks *_Nullable DMTasksFromData(NSData *data, NSError **error)
{
    @try {
        id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:error];
        return *error ? nil : [DMTasks fromJSONDictionary:json];
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"JSONSerialization" code:-1 userInfo:@{ @"exception": exception }];
        return nil;
    }
}

DMTasks *_Nullable DMTasksFromJSON(NSString *json, NSStringEncoding encoding, NSError **error)
{
    return DMTasksFromData([json dataUsingEncoding:encoding], error);
}

NSData *_Nullable DMTasksToData(DMTasks *tasks, NSError **error)
{
    @try {
        id json = [tasks JSONDictionary];
        NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:json options:kNilOptions error:error];
        return *error ? nil : data;
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"JSONSerialization" code:-1 userInfo:@{ @"exception": exception }];
        return nil;
    }
}

NSString *_Nullable DMTasksToJSON(DMTasks *tasks, NSStringEncoding encoding, NSError **error)
{
    NSData *data = DMTasksToData(tasks, error);
    return data ? [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:encoding] : nil;
}

@implementation DMTasks
+ (NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *)properties
{
    static NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *properties;
    return properties = properties ? properties : @{
        @"title": @"title",
        @"revision": @"revision",
        @"tasks": @"tasks",
        @"another_string": @"anotherString",
    };
}

+ (_Nullable instancetype)fromData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *_Nullable *)error
{
    return DMTasksFromData(data, error);
}

+ (_Nullable instancetype)fromJSON:(NSString *)json encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding error:(NSError *_Nullable *)error
{
    return DMTasksFromJSON(json, encoding, error);
}

+ (instancetype)fromJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    return dict ? [[DMTasks alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:dict] : nil;
}

- (instancetype)initWithJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict];
        _tasks = map(_tasks, λ(id x, [DMTask fromJSONDictionary:x]));
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setValue:(nullable id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    [super setValue:value forKey:DMTasks.properties[key]];
}

- (NSDictionary *)JSONDictionary
{
    id dict = [[self dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:DMTasks.properties.allValues] mutableCopy];

    for (id jsonName in DMTasks.properties) {
        id propertyName = DMTasks.properties[jsonName];
        if (![jsonName isEqualToString:propertyName]) {
            dict[jsonName] = dict[propertyName];
            [dict removeObjectForKey:propertyName];
        }
    }

    [dict addEntriesFromDictionary:@{
        @"tasks": map(_tasks, λ(id x, [x JSONDictionary])),
    }];

    return dict;
}

- (NSData *_Nullable)toData:(NSError *_Nullable *)error
{
    return DMTasksToData(self, error);
}

- (NSString *_Nullable)toJSON:(NSStringEncoding)encoding error:(NSError *_Nullable *)error
{
    return DMTasksToJSON(self, encoding, error);
}
@end

@implementation DMTask
+ (NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *)properties
{
    static NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *properties;
    return properties = properties ? properties : @{
        @"name": @"name",
        @"repeat": @"repeat",
        @"sub_tasks": @"subTasks",
    };
}

+ (instancetype)fromJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    return dict ? [[DMTask alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:dict] : nil;
}

- (instancetype)initWithJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict];
        _subTasks = map(_subTasks, λ(id x, [DMSubTask fromJSONDictionary:x]));
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setValue:(nullable id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    [super setValue:value forKey:DMTask.properties[key]];
}

- (NSDictionary *)JSONDictionary
{
    id dict = [[self dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:DMTask.properties.allValues] mutableCopy];

    for (id jsonName in DMTask.properties) {
        id propertyName = DMTask.properties[jsonName];
        if (![jsonName isEqualToString:propertyName]) {
            dict[jsonName] = dict[propertyName];
            [dict removeObjectForKey:propertyName];
        }
    }

    [dict addEntriesFromDictionary:@{
        @"sub_tasks": map(_subTasks, λ(id x, [x JSONDictionary])),
    }];

    return dict;
}
@end

@implementation DMSubTask
+ (NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *)properties
{
    static NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *properties;
    return properties = properties ? properties : @{
        @"name": @"name",
        @"repeat": @"repeat",
    };
}

+ (instancetype)fromJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    return dict ? [[DMSubTask alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:dict] : nil;
}

- (instancetype)initWithJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSDictionary *)JSONDictionary
{
    return [self dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:DMSubTask.properties.allValues];
}
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Now you can create an instance of `DMTasks *myTasks`, set whatever values or subtasks you'd like, then use `[myTasks toJSON:NSUTF8Encoding error:&error]` to convert to JSON.